# JavaScript Create an array from a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I want to calculate the age of some persons(birthyears are stored inside an array) using a function and then creating another array with the ages from the for loop but i keep getting an empty array. Can anyone help?

```
 const years = [1991, 1994, 2008, 2020];
 const calcAge = function (birthYear) {
  return 2021 - birthYear;
};
 const age = [];
 for (let i = 0; i > years.length; i++) {
  calcAge(i);
  age.push(i);
}
 console.log(age);
```

Comment: https://press.rebus.community/programmingfundamentals/chapter/for-loop/ Check this out.

Comment: `i > years.length` will always be `false`.

Comment: i starts with 0 and the condition is that is should be greater then 4(arr length). This is never true and hence empty array.

Comment: You also might want to change the code inside your loop but once you fix the for loop conditions, doing console.log() will let you know what the issue is.

Comment: Also, what value(s) do you want in your `age` array?  Do you want `i`, the index from the loop?  Or the value returned from `calcAge()`?

Comment: This main problem is complexity, Just keep it simple... Use `years.map(birthYear => 2021 - birthYear)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your for loop condition isn't right. it should be switched from i > years.length to i < years.length. You also need to push the return value of your age calculation to the ages array

```
const years = [1991, 1994, 2008, 2020];
 const calcAge = function (birthYear) {
  return 2021 - birthYear;
};
 const ages = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
  const age = calcAge(years[i]);
  ages.push(age);
}
 console.log(ages);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're simply using `>` instead of `<`:

```js
const years = [1991, 1994, 2008, 2020];

const calcAge = function (birthYear) {
  return 2021 - birthYear;
};

const age = [];
for (let i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
  age.push(calcAge(years[i]));
}
console.log(age);
```

The loop should run *until* `i` becomes equal to `years.length`. If `i` starts off as `0`, the comparison `i > years.length` will be `false` (since `0 > 4 === false`), and the loop will immediately terminate.

I've made one more improvement for you; I switched:

```
calcAge(i);
age.push(i);
```

to:

```
age.push(calcAge(years[i]));
```

The former has a number of issues; you pass `i`, the index, instead of `years[i]`, the actual age. And you perform the `calcAge` computation but never actually store the answer. The latter fixes these issues.

As suggested by Nur, you could simplify your code using `map`:

```js
const years = [ 1991, 1994, 2008, 2020 ];
const ages = years.map(year => 2021 - year);
console.log(ages);
```

Comment: use `for..of` loop

Comment: `for..of` or `Array.prototype.map` would be cleaner solutions, but I want to address the actual question asked by the OP.